# Can't use enter key to execute commands in zsh

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, xterm, gnome-terminal

I recently installed zsh (v5.1.1) on a new ubuntu setup, but when I switch to it in gnome-terminal, I cannot seem to use to the enter key to execute the command. The only way I can execute commands is by using `CTRL+J`. I can replicate this across other term emulators like `xterm` and `uxterm`.

All other keys work fine, including the HOME, END, PGUP, PGDOWN, DEL and INSERT keys.

I've installed `zsh` so many times on other systems, but have never run into a problem like this before. What do I need to change to get the enter key to work normally?

My `/etc/zsh/zshrc` file:

```
typeset -ga debian_missing_features

if [[ -z "$DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES" ]] &&
[[ "$TERM" != 'emacs' ]]
then

    typeset -A key
    key=(
        BackSpace  "${terminfo[kbs]}"
        Home       "${terminfo[khome]}"
        End        "${terminfo[kend]}"
        Insert     "${terminfo[kich1]}"
        Delete     "${terminfo[kdch1]}"
        Up         "${terminfo[kcuu1]}"
        Down       "${terminfo[kcud1]}"
        Left       "${terminfo[kcub1]}"
        Right      "${terminfo[kcuf1]}"
        PageUp     "${terminfo[kpp]}"
        PageDown   "${terminfo[knp]}"
    )

    function bind2maps () {
        local i sequence widget
        local -a maps

        while [[ "$1" != "--" ]]; do
            maps+=( "$1" )
            shift
        done
        shift

        sequence="${key[$1]}"
        widget="$2"

        [[ -z "$sequence" ]] && return 1

        for i in "${maps[@]}"; do
            bindkey -M "$i" "$sequence" "$widget"
        done
    }

    bind2maps emacs             -- BackSpace   backward-delete-char
    bind2maps       viins       -- BackSpace   vi-backward-delete-char
    bind2maps             vicmd -- BackSpace   vi-backward-char
    bind2maps emacs             -- Home        beginning-of-line
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Home        vi-beginning-of-line
    bind2maps emacs             -- End         end-of-line
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- End         vi-end-of-line
    bind2maps emacs viins       -- Insert      overwrite-mode
    bind2maps             vicmd -- Insert      vi-insert
    bind2maps emacs             -- Delete      delete-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Delete      vi-delete-char
    bind2maps emacs viins vicmd -- Up          up-line-or-history
    bind2maps emacs viins vicmd -- Down        down-line-or-history
    bind2maps emacs             -- Left        backward-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Left        vi-backward-char
    bind2maps emacs             -- Right       forward-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Right       vi-forward-char

    # Make sure the terminal is in application mode, when zle is
    # active. Only then are the values from $terminfo valid.
    if (( ${+terminfo[smkx]} )) && (( ${+terminfo[rmkx]} )); then
        function zle-line-init () {
            emulate -L zsh
            printf '%s' ${terminfo[smkx]}
        }
        function zle-line-finish () {
            emulate -L zsh
            printf '%s' ${terminfo[rmkx]}
        }
        zle -N zle-line-init
        zle -N zle-line-finish
    else
        for i in {s,r}mkx; do
            (( ${+terminfo[$i]} )) || debian_missing_features+=($i)
        done
        unset i
    fi

    unfunction bind2maps
fi # [[ -z "$DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES" ]] && [[ "$TERM" != 'emacs' ]]

zstyle ':completion:*:sudo:*' command-path /usr/local/sbin \
                                        /usr/local/bin  \
                                        /usr/sbin       \
                                        /usr/bin        \
                                        /sbin           \
                                        /bin            \
                                        /usr/X11R6/bin

(( ${+aliases[run-help]} )) && unalias run-help
autoload -Uz run-help

# If you don't want compinit called here, place the line
# skip_global_compinit=1
# in your $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv or $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
if [[ -z "$skip_global_compinit" ]]; then
autoload -U compinit
compinit
fi
```

Comment: First, I'd check the key bindings for `CTRL+J` and `CTRL+M`, e.g. with this command `bindkey | grep -E "^\"\^(J|M)"`.

Comment: I got `accept-line` for both. `"^J" accept-line
"^M" accept-line`

Comment: Does the `ENTER` key produce new lines, after starting `cat` without any arguments? Try also, if it works as expected when invoking _zsh_ without any config via `zsh -f`.

Comment: The `ENTER` key does not produce any new lines. However, `zsh -f` worked. Looks like something in my `/etc/zsh/zshrc` then?

Comment: Does `ENTER` actually generate either of the key sequences `^M` and `^J`. You should be able to check this with `CTRL+V` followed by `ENTER`.

Answer (score 8):

To output the character zsh associates with each key, type <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then the character (where <kbd>⌃</kbd> is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).

For example:

- my return key outputs: `^M`
- my enter key outputs: `^[OM`

To make my enter key behave like my return key:

```
bindkey '^[OM' accept-line
```